# React select sticky option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How to make one option in react-select stick. (i.e: like position fixed, it will stay at the top even when we scroll through options in the drop-down)

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to add css on react-select ?

```js
import React from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select options={options} style={{position: 'fixed !important'}} />
)
```

Kind regards,
Kilian GOËTZ.

Comment: No, I wanted to keep my first option in the dropdown to stay sticky. And No  I haven't added any CSS to make it sticky. I tried though. But it's not looking that great. But it's working.

Comment: @wgetDJ Did you find a solution to this? I am in need of this.